# Microsoft Edge Zoom Issue

Tags: windows-10, browser, zoom, microsoft-edge

I have a weird persistent issue with Edge browser. All websites load up super zoomed away and it is a default state, so reloading the page zooms back out. I cleared cache and cookies, but for no help. The issue is the same in browser anonymous mode and in Windows safe mode. Microsoft help desk didn't help. I have a Surface Pro 3 with Windows 10 installed.

How Facebook looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Edge before performing this procedure.

Open the Registry Editor (type `regedit` in Start menu). Open the following folders/keys: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` → `Local Settings` → `Software` → `Microsoft` → `Windows` → `CurrentVersion` → `AppContainer` → `Storage` → `microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe` → `MicrosoftEdge` → `Zoom`. Double-click the entry called `ZoomFactor`, set the Base to *Decimal*, change the data to *100000*, and click OK. Exit the Registry Editor.

Reopen Edge to test the new zoom level (100%). You can also change that value to get custom zoom factors like 105%; the value is the zoom level in percent times 1000. Source: [this Microsoft thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/apps_windows_10-msedge/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-edge-zoom-default-of/fb83cf60-8c8e-454c-9522-454ccbc30d0b?auth=1).